# How to copy one list onto another via assignment operator overloading? C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, singly-linked-list

My header file

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList;

public:
    Node(string& name, int num) :studentName(name), RUID(num)
    {
        this->next = NULL;
    }

private:
    string studentName;
    int RUID;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    LinkedList operator+(const LinkedList &i); //Done
    LinkedList operator=(const LinkedList &j);

    void makeLists(int n); //Done
    void addNode(LinkedList &i);
    void removeNode();
    void printList();
    void printElement();
    void sortList();

private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
};

#endif
```

My function

```
LinkedList LinkedList::operator=(LinkedList &j)
{
    if (&j != this)
    {
        Node* temp = j.head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            j.head = j.head->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = j.head;
        }

        temp = j.head;

        while (temp != nullptr)
        {

        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I've tried for hours but I'm stumped as to what I should do within my second while loop. In fact, I don't even know if my operator overloading function is even remotely correct but that was the best I was able to come up within the past few hours or so

Comment: Something for you to consider: When you're copying one list to another, do you want the result to be that both lists refer to the same elements? That is, if I change one, then the other is changed too? If no, consider adding some `new` in that operator. Also, consider what you're returning (`LinkedList`), which requires you create a copy of `*this`. Is this really what you want to consider. Finally, think about what guarantees you want to make about the list assigning from (The `B` in `A = B`.) Should you guarantee that it's left unchanged?

Comment: Not so much that both lists refer to the same elements but rather they have the same elements and, yes, in that scenario B should remain unchanged. I'm merely trying to change A. How would you recommend I go about copying one list to another? In fact, could I possibly just clone one list and return that?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, let's fix the code that you have already written. Looks like you have a perfectly written "removeNode()" class method. You haven't actually shown it, but I'll assume that it works perfectly.

If that is the case, it's a waste and duplicated code to also go through the motions of deleting the list's existing nodes. You should have already written this code as part of your removeNode() method. So, replace the code that you have written here with a simple loop that invokes removeNode(), until the list is empty.

After you've gone through this excersize, you should be able to figure it out all by yourself that your second while() loop should simply iterate over the nodes in the other list, and use this list's addNode() method to add a copy of each node from the other list, to this list.

Comment: Oh no, I haven't written my removeNode() method at all yet. I'm kind of going through my methods one at a time, in order. Only the ones I have written //Done next to are finished

Comment: Well, write removeNode() first. Then write addNode(). Then you have this operator function already written, mostly. You're doing this in a slightly wrong order. You implement the simple methods first, then the harder ones, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh alright, I'll get on that but, even if I had both of them made, how would I use them for the assignment operator overloading?

Comment: By observing the fact that operator= removes all existing nodes from the list, then adds a copy of the nodes from the other list. As I wrote, by that time, you will already have written the code that removes and adds nodes from the list, so all you have to do is use them in your operator=.